# Certificate keys - conversion

Tags: openssl

For purpose of testing I need to enable SSL on IIS8 (On Amazon servers). I created a test key using IIS and I exported that key in *.pfx format.
Now in Load Balancer setting I need to have that key converted to *.PEM format. I did just that using https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

When I open newly generated *.PEM key I have two fields:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
key is here...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

and also I have

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
certificate is in here...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Now when I enter those values in LoadBalancer, it always complains with:

Invalid Public Key Certificate.

I have tried pasting both values with ---BEGIN and without to same result...

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the following error:

> routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line node.js

No matter what I do I always get that error. Other people who got same error, suggested to add extra enter on header and footer of the request. In my case it did not help. What helped me is Notepad++ and EoL conversion.

I guess you can do it with other editors, but I used Notepad++.
Just edit-->EoL Conversion and make sure Windows is selected.

Hopefully it will save time for other people who experience the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

For everybody already had .pem format and still getting "Invalid Public Key Certificate", here is my solution.

The certificate chain bundle is actually formed by 2 certificates, one after the other: inverting the order of the two worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This link provided me with the solution:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56937

The tech support from Amazon detailed what commands need to be used. Basically use first which is:
--This will get you a key
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -out private.key.1 -nodes -nocerts

and use this one as will to get a certificate itself:
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the "Invalid Public Key Certificate" for a different reason. It turned out the clock on the machine I made the certificate on was half an hour fast, so the certificate was not valid yet! To check this, use:

```
openssl x509 -in yourcert.pem -text -noout
```

And check the timestamp after "Validity / Not Before:".

Half an hour wasn't too long to wait. Without changing the form contents, I hit submit again after that time and it went through ok.